# Do I need Ubuntu to effectively develop Unittest Framework Tests for embedded C Projects?

Tags: c, linux, unit-testing

I am trying to get started developing unittests for my embedded system, actually its a firmware that was already developed a while ago, now we want to add CI to it and start this by writing unittests.

I read blogs like
https://dmitryfrank.com/articles/unit_testing_embedded_c_applications
or https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/unit-testing-basics and they recommend to implement the unittests via a unittest framework as unity, cpputest and so on and so on. I tried to figure out how to make this run on my windows machine that I use at work but it seems tedious and prone to problems etc.
I also tried to start working with the microsoft vs unit testing framework but got discouraged after running into problems here, too. I think this can't be so hard, it shouldn't take so much effort to start writing the first littlest test...

Do you have experience with this and what would you recommend? Is it viable to do this on Windows? Should I push my boss to let me use a VM, WSL or a Machine that runs Ubuntu? In the end I would like to transfer the CI System to a lab pc (edit: this pc would then also be connected to the hardware, flash it, maybe run a debug build on it and compile some answers that it gets from the hardware... but now I want to talk about the unit test), so if I start developing on Ubuntu now, I will have to deal with this lateron, too...

Maybe a lot of thoughts but I feel a bit overwhelmed with the problem and don't know how to start.
Thanks for you replies, people!

Edit: The discussion I am looking for is not about whether unit testing for embedded systems is useful or the right approach (also interesting but I would like to seperate it) . It's about the question whether it can be fully developed under Windows or whether a Linux System is necessary to be efficient.

Comment: Unit tests of embedded systems are carried out on-chip, not in some "test suite". Simulating hardware and real-time performance in some PC environment is nonsense. Creating tests for embedded systems usually involves developing some hardware for such in parallel with the product: logging features, test points, pogo pin systems, whatever might apply. Or those preaching "TDD" might write tests together with the driver code and then run it on the target as an isolated test.

Comment: @Lundin I disagree, it really depends on the actual case. If one can abstract the hardware away (and then possibly mock it), there is nothing that prevents from running the unit tests on a different system. The difficulty here might be the fact that HW/driver code is tighlty coupled with the rest of the logic, regardless if it's a design flaw or a decision due to limitation (e.g. due to hardware limitations).

Comment: @alagner You cannot trivially or meaningfully simulate real-time performance in a PC simulator. Nor can you simulate that one mandatory silicon bug in the MCU. Sure there might be completely hardware-independent parts that could be tested separately.  Maybe.

Comment: But testers should focus on creating as useful tests as possible, including tests that can be used in production. There are so many possible tests that are far more relevant than running code in some artificial PC fluff suite. Including oscilloscopes, loggers, spectrum analysers, sw tools like static/dynamic analysis, code coverage... I can go on. The PC fluff suite doesn't even reach top 100 in the most meaningful test tools for a generic embedded systems product.

Comment: @Lundin imho the main purpose of test first strategy (or unit tests in general) is not testing per se, but a. forcing oneself to write clearly-defined interfaces, thus making the code (self)-documenting, b. protecting that clarity - if one changes the interface, test fails and it fails quickly, possibly when buidling.

Comment: thanks for your experienced comments! I share your opinion that the system will not be fully verified with unit tests.

Comment: @jkbs1337 it never will be, but it's not a good excuse to not writing them ;)
Have a look at [this](https://github.com/dawikur/crow). It's a simple one (and in C++, not C) so might not be fully relevant to your case (especially when you have lots of legacy) but when you're just trying different approaches it might bo worth taking a look.

Comment: @alagner Those are good points, but the most effective test for that might be peer code review. Particularly with some merciless old veteran present. Making a sound program design is very qualified work, someone with less than 5-10 years of experience will never get it right by themselves. In which case the solution isn't TDD but to teach them how to design.

Comment: @alagner "... but it's not a good excuse to not writing them ;)..." - exactly

Comment: @Lundin I really agree that we also need some hardware testing but unit tests were decided to be also one part of the puzzle and now its my job to implement them...

Comment: @Lundin granted, but getting it wrong is part of the learning process ;) Also, properly done tdd is a tool supposed to help one get it "better than worse", so is code review (and many other things, like static analysis, CI etc.). I'm the last one to advocate for 100% coverage on unit tests, imho that's a waste of effort, but a reasonably written unit test suite increases the "code hygiene" greatly to me.

Comment: I am using different environments (Windows, Linux and BSD systems). I found that Google test is an acceptable framework that can easily be used in Windows/MSVC and also on BSD or Linux systems. Of course you will not test specific hardware features, nor real-time behaviour, but it can help to avoid general algorithmic errors.

Comment: `whether it can be fully developed under Windows or whether a Linux System is necessary to be efficient` @jkbs1337 depending on your setup it might or might not be ;)
What toolchain do you use for target platform development? Do you have licensing limitations (or maybe you already have MSVC corporate licenses)? How does this whole thing work with your CI? Difficult to say really, Windows might be enough (I'm saying it as a Linux-advocate;)) provided you have the right tools and know how to handle it in broader context.

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks for joining the discussion, since I am new to unit testing I haven't used google test yet but "easily be used in Windows/MSVC" is something that sounds intriging...

Comment: @alagner I am completely new to CI but I can use MSVC if I want to. So far I program on Microchip Studio (I think it was Atmel Studio before) with an XC8 Compiler.

Comment: @alagner "(I'm saying it as a Linux-advocate;)" - that honors you! I wouldnt consider myself a Linux User but I start to see that it might really benefit me. I tried to use an Oracle VM or the WSL but it seems its blocked at my company...

Comment: You should look for a unit test framework that allows running the tests on the embedded target. IMHO you can start running the unit tests on a PC, but the code may behave differently on the target. So the final goal is to run the tests (also) on the target. For open source unit test frameworks, according to my experience, it is often easier to get it running on a Linux system.

Comment: *For open source unit test frameworks, according to my experience, it is often easier to get it running on a Linux system*. I absolutely agree! That is the reason why I mentionned that Google Test could be used on a Windows-MSVC environment...